# How to get data from another project in REDCap

Tags: database, redcap

I create a new project in REDCap and I need to add a new record and get record about the first name and last name from another project. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished with two calls to the REDCap API.

1. Retrieve the data from the source project.  Either retrieve the all the rows (for a few columns) and filter , or use the `filter` API argument.
2. Write the record(s) to the destination project.

There are REDCap API packages in several languages, which abstract away a lot of the cURL details and let you focus on the important aspects of the operations.  The [REDCap-Tools](http://redcap-tools.github.io/projects/) lists the packages, as well as several tutorials and troubleshooting documents.

http://redcap-tools.github.io/projects/

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this aim with the external module [Auto Record Generation](https://github.com/vanderbilt-redcap/auto-record-generation).

Best,