# REDCap, transfer data from a project to another project

Tags: api, redcap

I work on REDCap, and I would transfer data from a project to another project:

- in Project 1, I have information in form "inclusion", with a field "code_ind"
- in Project 2, I would like to create a new record each time that a new form "inclusion" has been filled in Project 1

I read that it could be possible [with API here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54688064/how-to-get-data-from-another-project-in-redcap):

- I activate API on the left hand side in Project 1,
- I retrieve example of code in API Playground

Now I can retrieve data of "inclusion_copy" fields of all "inclusion" forms from Project 1, for example with R.

My question: how can I use this API system to create new record in Project 2?

Best,
Marc

edit: I mixed the terms form and record, I corrected

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a solution, a great external module was developed for this purpose: [Auto Record Generation](https://github.com/vanderbilt-redcap/auto-record-generation). With this module:

- you choose which field of Project 1 must have a value to create a new record in Project 2,
- you can choose to give the same record id in Project 2 as in Project 1,
- if you have fields with the same name in both projects, you can choose to transfer the data when creating the new record (eg gender, name, etc).